# sql case statement in where?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

```
select t1.customer_code as doc_num, CONVERT(VARCHAR,t2.created_on,103) as doc_date,
t2.sap_cardcode as sap_doc_num ,t2.void_flg,t2.status_ind,t2.err_msg
from customer t1
inner join sap_customer t2 on t1.id = t2.customer_id
where t2.status_ind = case when @test = 'todo' then t2.status_ind='1' else t2.status_ind='0' END
```

Above is the select statement that i need to do, based on the where statement i need to pass a param to determine which want should it execute.
Status Ind = 1 or Status Ind = 0

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: incorrect syntax near "="

Comment: It's usually better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 3):

I have modified the Case part a little in your query. Hope this helps:

```
select t1.customer_code as doc_num, CONVERT(VARCHAR,t2.created_on,103) as doc_date,t2.sap_cardcode as sap_doc_num ,t2.void_flg,t2.status_ind,t2.err_msg
from customer t1
inner join sap_customer t2 on t1.id = t2.customer_id
where t2.status_ind = case when @test = 'todo' then '1' else '0' END
```

OR you can use case like below:

```
where t2.status_ind = case @test when 'todo' then '1' else '0' END
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `CASE` statement needs to be modified

```
case when @test = 'todo' then '1' else '0' END
```

Since, you are going to compare `where t2.status_ind`. So, you need to return some value from `CASE` instead of setting it.